# How to show missing values of attributes more than 50% on HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a dataset of columns
**model, mileage, manufacture, engine_displacement, engine_power, body_type, color_slug, skt_year, transmission, door_count, seat_count, fuel_type, date_created, date_seen, price
**

To see how many missing values you have in each attribute and to show how many missing values in each column we have more than 50% missing values.

How can to achieve this in hive?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a SQL in hive -
to calculate how many nulls in a column. Unfortunately you need to calculate for each column separately.

```
select 
tot_count,
null_model count_null_model,
100*null_model/tot_count percent_null_model,
null_mileage count_null_mileage,
100*null_mileage/tot_count percent_null_mileage,
...
from 
(select count(*) tot_count,
sum( if(mileage is null,1,0) as null_mileage,
sum( if(model is null,1,0) as null_model,
...
from my_table)rs
```

Here
`sum( if(mileage is null,1,0) as null_mileage` - calculates how many null values exist in the table.

Outer `100*null_mileage/tot_count percent_null_mileage` - is calculating % of null. If you awnt you can put a filter here like this `100*null_mileage/tot_count >50`