# How to count columns with more than 50% missing values

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

These are the two queries I'm editing any clue how to count the columns with more than 50% missing values

Column names are - color_slug, household

````
select avg(case when color_slug='' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as color_slug_null_p
from used_cars;

select
avg(count(*) from used_cars where color_slug='" then 1.0 else 0.0 end ) as color_slug_null_p ```
````

Comment: How does this differ from your last 2 posts? Averaging doesn't count, by the way. Surely you want to group by and sum

Comment: Agree @OneCricketeer ... For OP, Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74322736/how-to-show-missing-values-of-attributes-more-than-50-on-hive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show missing values of attributes more than 50% on HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74322736/how-to-show-missing-values-of-attributes-more-than-50-on-hive)